# How to make android actionbar background image repeat x and y

Tags: android, xml

How can I make the following style repeat the image x and y for the android action bar.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:background" >@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Under drawable folder, add your my_background.png file, which represents the image to be repeated.

Still under drawable folder, create a action_bar_bg.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/my_background"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Mind the `android:tileMode="repeat"` statement. This will instruct android to repeat the image.

Open your styles.xml or whatever you have used to set your styles, and configure your background image based on the bitmap above:

```
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

I have noticed Android has some issues when redering Actionbar depending on the API level you are using. In this case, using a newer API is better to avoid trouble and customization / hacking. So you need to doublecheck your target API, styles, drawables, layouts, colors and themes used in order to figure if they are all linked and set.

Once bitmap is declared it is easy to set your repeatable background programatically:

```
//highlight visited item using image declared in 'bitmap' tag
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
   view.setBackground(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg)
   );
else
   view.setBackgroundDrawable(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.another_action_bar_bg)
   );
```

If you wish to explore even more background coding, I suggest you to have a go with `BitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY` method

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
             R.drawable.action_bar_bg);
BitmapDrawable bdw = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
bdw.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, 
                  Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

yourView.setBackgroundDrawable(bdw);
```

I hope this help you and others!